# Restrict IFRAME to change parent URL

Tags: jquery, iframe, mobile-browser, url-masking

This question has been wandering around internet but there is no clear suggestion. I am posting this question to get a clear and direct answer.

I have a website. In the website I have an iFRAME. The iFRAME loads with a URL. The iFRAME URL/Page has a java script that checks the following:

```
If Browser = Mobile Browser 
Then top location = self location
```

-> this changes the URL of the browser to the iFRAME URL.

Is there any way to stop the URL Change ?

PS : iFRAME URL is in different domain.

Comment: no, you can't access cross domain iframe unless you have control of code within the other domain and can set `document.domain` so each match

Comment: No. I am not saying I should. I am just saying that if the iframe tries to change the parent URL.. how to stop that ?

Comment: you can't prevent the script inside iframe from running